# Root MenuItem Visibility binding

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I need to a root `MenuItem` `Collapsed` based on a condition.  I can get sub - MenuItem of the root menu to Collapsed but not the root.

Background:  Based on settings I need to `MenuItems` to be `Visible` or `Collapsed`.  This kind of works.  For sub `MenuItem` it works perfectly;

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem  Header="Root Menu Item" >
        <MenuItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyResource}, Path=MySetting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Menu Item">
            <MenuItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyResource}, Path=MySetting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Changing the value for MySetting between true and false makes the "Sub Menu Item" disappear or a appear, but has no effect on the Root Menu Item.  I am at a lost as to why.

Comment: Why you don't just use the BoolenToVisbilityConverter? `<MenuItem Visibility="{Binidng Path=MySetting, Source={StaticResource MyResource}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />`  Are your properties static?

Comment: That fixed it.  If you post this as an answer, I will mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple Binding it's better and easier to use an `IValueConverter`, e.g. the preincluded `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Usage example:

```
<SomeParentElement.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
</SomeParentElement.Resources>
```

---

```
<Menu Visibility="{Binding Path=MySetting, 
                           Source={StaticResource MyResource}, 
                           Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
```